# SELECT from table and then SELECT on this recordset and then return all to caller

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, subquery

Is there a way to do the following in one stored procedure/UDF:

1. Select from a table
2. Select from the result from the select in pt 1
3. Select again on the result from the select in pt 1
4. Return all three results from pt 1, 2 and 3 to the caller

PS: The three results would be recordsets and not single values.

---

Ok, I'll try to make the question clearer. I don't think I can achieve what I want with sub queries..

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT BrandID, TypeID, CECategoryID, BrandName, ModelID, ModelName 
FROM Boats 
WHERE BrandID = @BrandID
"INTO @Recordset1"


SELECT Count(ModelID) AS ModelsPerType
FROM @Recordset1
GROUP BY TypeID
"INTO @Recordset2"


SELECT Count(ModelID) AS ModelsPerCECategory
FROM @Recordset1
GROUP BY CECategoryID
"INTO @Recordset3"


"RETURN Recordset1, Recordset2, Recordset3"
```

I know I cant write the things I did in hyphens, but it is to illustrate what I am looking for. In my code (web application) I would like to call a Stored Procedure holding the code above and receive back the three recordsets.

Comment: uhmm, can post sample records with desired result?

Comment: Which DB engine are you using ?

Comment: they're called subqueries or subselects:  http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-sql-subselects-to-consolidate-queries/1045787

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @mcalex I looked at subqueries. But is it possible to return the results from both the main query AND the subquery(ies)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM ( SELECT *
              FROM BIG_DATA_TABLE )
       WHERE blah blah )
WHERE blah blah
ORDER BY etc
```

This should work in most databases including [Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

I don't get point 4.  How do you want to return all three results?  By adding the rows of subsequent results to the first table of results?

You *could* write the three individual queries (the main, the main with the first subselect and the main with the two subqueries) and join each query's results to the next with a `union`, but the three queries would need to contain the same number and type of columns, but that would be yukky.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE
UNION
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE ) WHERE subquery_stuff 
UNION
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE ) WHERE subquery_stuff ) WHERE sub_subquery_stuff )
```

Edit:  OIC

If you just put the three queries into the stored procedure, you should get three result sets.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj691402

Comment: Re; point 4: I don't want to join the results from the different selscts. I want them to be returned separately.

I put your code in a SP, I will only receive the records from the top select. What I am looking for is to be able to separately return all the three results from the three selects you have in your code.

Comment: I may be wrong but do not think you can return 3 diff. "recordsets" from a single nested query. To return a recordset you may use Ref Cursor, for ex. But it is unclear to me what you really want... Keep it simple - write 3 separate selects (may be functions within procedure or package) if you are panning to use this in SP-stored procedure I assume. The K.I.S.S. method is the best and cheapest to the company you may work for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
        Select * From (Select * From (Select * from Table1)T1)T2 --pt3
        Select * From (Select * from Table1)T1 --pt2
        Select * from Table1 --pt1
```

I have edited the query after looking at you updated requirement,
This query will show 3 record sets and you can use them according to your requirement

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.. Does this mean I can return the T1, T2 and the top select to the caller?

Comment: Look into the edited query this will give you 3 record sets, you will be able to return all the 3 to the caller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the counts alongside the detail data retrieved in the first query, you could use [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) aggregate functions:

```
SELECT
  BrandID,
  TypeID,
  CECategoryID,
  BrandName,
  ModelID,
  ModelName,
  COUNT(ModelID) OVER (PARTITION BY TypeID      ) AS ModelsPerType,
  COUNT(ModelID) OVER (PARTITION BY CECategoryID) AS ModelsPerCECategory
FROM Boats 
WHERE BrandID = @BrandID
;
```